# function with many parameters in python

Tags: python

I have 2 functions and the first fuction returns 10 variables. these 10 varaibles are then used in the second fuction. this obviosuly gets lengthy and messy. can anyone suggest a batter way to do it. below example are my functions with snippit of 6 variables/parameters. you can see when i call the second fuction i have to pass in all the parameters and i want a shorter way of doing it.

```
def get_market_caps():
    rank 25 = 2500*4
    rank 35 = 4500*2
    rank 45 = 6500*2
    rank 55 = 200*7
    rank 65 = 72340*50
    rank 75 = 4923*9
    return rank25, rank35, rank45, rank55, rank65, rank75

def get new_market_caps(rank25, rank35, rank45, rank55, rank65, rank75):
    pct_move_1 = rank25/54-1
    pct_move_2 = rank35/4-1
    pct_move_3 = rank45/545-1
    pct_move_4 = rank55/98-1
    pct_move_5 = rank65/564-1
    pct_move_6 = rank75/5423-1
    return pct_move_1, pct_move_2, pct_move_3, pct_move_4, pct_move_5, pct_move_6

rank25, rank35, rank45, rank55, rank65, rank75 = get_market_caps()
moves = get_new_market_caps(rank25, rank35, rank45, rank55, rank65, rank75)
```

Comment: You aren't "returning 10 variables", it's very important to understand, you don't return *variables* you return *values/objects*. In this case, you return a *tuple* object of length 10.

Comment: Can you clarify what the issue is? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the return value as a tuple and then unpack it into the other function:

```
ranks = get_market_caps()
moves = get_new_market_caps(*ranks)
```

Comment: Upvoted but perhaps mention that this only works if return values from the function are in the correct order.